# Build modulable info pages with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, include

I would like to create a website which can provides informations pages about specific product that i could be able to modify and generate easily.

This could be something like this :

> http://www.example.com/list/*product1*.php

All i need is to easily generate pages with a function to personalize its content ( with JSON maybe ? )
All my pages are included in php with something like this ( i didn't post the entire thing but here is the idea ) :

```
include 'views/partials/head.php';
include 'views/partials/header.php';
include 'views/pages/'.$page.'.php';
include 'views/partials/footer.php';
include 'views/partials/foot.php';
```

So here are my questions :

- How can I make my pages structure 
  recognizable to set it up with special includes ?
- Which way is the most efficient to personalize it ?

I know that the answer is probably quite obvious for most of you and i didn't know what to google to find the answer ... Your help will be very apreciated :)
If you didn't understand the question feel free to ask about it in coments !

EDIT : My question seems unclear , here are some explanation :
Let's say that i want to code a selling platform and I want an information page for each of my products. These information pages will be exactly the same except for some details as : The pictures , the name of the product , the price ect...
How can I generate them easily in PHP ? I don't want to create a single page for each of my product :/

EDIT 2 : 
Okay i managed to get something ...

- Firstly I check if the current url match to the "product info" architecture ( here if the url contain "/list"
- Then I cut the URL string to get which product is asked
- Finally  I want to include an appropriate customized PHP file to fit with my product , I don't know how to manage this part. Here is my code :

```
if (strpos($curUrl, 'list/') !== false) {
  $listing=substr($curUrl,22);//The listing variable is the name of the product
  include 'views/partials/head.php';
  include 'views/partials/header.php';
  //INCLUDE personalized content
  include 'views/partials/footer.php';
  include 'views/partials/foot.php';
}
else{
include 'views/partials/head.php';
include 'views/partials/header.php';
include 'views/pages/'.$page.'.php';
include 'views/partials/footer.php';
include 'views/partials/foot.php';

}
```

So is it possible to execute a dynamic include or maybe pass the $listing variable to JS to generate the proper page ( maybe with JSON once again ? )

Comment: What exactly is your question? Try and be more specific about what you have so far and what you want to achieve. One question at a time.

Comment: My main question is the following : How can I easily add/remove/edit pages with the same structure , but with different content ( like product pages on a amazon for exemple). Create by hand all the pages seems really heavy and not optimized.

Comment: Use a php micro framework to help you with your routing

Comment: http://flightphp.com/learn/ Is this that kind of framework ? Thanks for your answer !